# Selenium Java: Chrome Webdriver findElement by xpath does not return expected value

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract text from an HTML table.

I use Selenium and chrome driver.

```
sResult = m_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/center/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[5]/a")).getText(); ///abbr
```

This is an extrat of the table:

[image]

I have tried the code on two tables, which their format was changed:

```
<a class="bluelink" href="fstats.php?champ=904&amp;team=470&amp;team2=406&amp;tour=110"><abbr title="that this then">1:0 (0:0)</abbr> </a>
```

[image]

and

```
<a class="bluelink" href="fstats.php?champ=804&amp;team=435&amp;team2=441&amp;tour=110">1:1</a>
```

[image]

For the first one I do get 1:0 (0:0) but for the latter - I get an empty string.

I can also tell that I tried the follwoing code on the latter format:

```
        List<WebElement> elemRes = elemTable.findElements(By.xpath("tr[" + i + "]/td"));

        for(int x = 0; x < elemRes.size(); x++){

            System.out.println(elemRes.get(x).getText());
        }
```

where i is the row index. I could get **all the cells text** printed to console except of the last one (the X:Y cell types). And the loop does reaches this cell, but prints nothing!

[image]

The reason for the change in the elements structure is by design and I have no influence on that.

Can you advise please?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please show us the selenium code that you are using to obtain the second string?  It's likely a problem in the xpath selector.  As Shubham Jain mentions below, if you are looking for a specific item, it would seem best for you to create an xpath or css selector which would be based on the href.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Yes, I will update the main question above in 1 minute. thank you for your time.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware isn;t the "& n b s p ;" plays role here?

Comment: I don't believe that this non-breaking space would make a difference.  in your loop above, try changing the xpath to "tr[" + i + "]/td/a", where you're actually asking for the text of the link.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Tried. Unbelievably the same results. Only the first four columns from the right are printed, but not the 1:1 :-(  Also, I remind you that the loop does take 5 iterations, so it seems to detect 5 cells in a row!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try below XPath:-

```
//a[@class='bluelink']
```

Try in your code as below:-

```
sResult = m_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='bluelink']")).getText();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you. It will not work, because the page contains many elements of this class, and I need only specific ones.

Comment: is this URL static in href? fstats.php?champ=904&amp;team=470&amp;team2=406&amp;tour=110

Comment: if yes and this URL is unique too then we can use this also to locate the element

Comment: I am not sure it is relevant here. I added Html images in the main question. Would you review them please? Maybe it can help... Thank you!

Comment: your URL numerical is dynamic .. it won't work unless you know that as a prerequisite